# Yii 2.0 authentication in UserIdentity without database

Tags: yii2

Any idea about authentication without using database?.
I have gone through the basic template. In that app/models/User.php ,they have provided validations based on

```
 private static $users = [
        '100' => [
            'id' => '100',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'admin',
            'authKey' => 'test100key',
            'accessToken' => '100-token',
        ],
        '101' => [
            'id' => '101',
            'username' => 'demo',
            'password' => 'demo',
            'authKey' => 'test101key',
            'accessToken' => '101-token',
        ],
    ];
```

But I want the login validation based on a different condition , for example if a variable satisfies some conditions , the he should be logged on. Or any idea on whether I can set `Identity` Manually?

I referred to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-identityinterface.html , it also mentions about only using database. Is it necessary to set `'authKey'` and  `'accessToken'` ?

Or anyone can explain the flow of authentication in Yii 2.0 , which values to be set , in which order ?

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own `IdentityInterface` and have user implement there. But altering your `loginForm.php` file at the `getUser()` and `validatePassword()` methods might work better.

Comment: Is it necessary to set authkey and accesstoken?

Comment: They are not necessary, mine are disabled.

Comment: I am getting error Getting unknown property: app\models\User::auth_key

Comment: where is that being called?

Comment: @tripsket can you show a sample how you modified  getUser() and validatePassword() methods ?

Comment: `LoginForm.php` uses `login()` to call `validatePassword()` which is the normal workflow. I had to change `validatePassword()` in both `LoginForm.php` and `User.php` models to meet my 'extra' validation needs (`User.php` being where most of the validation code is handled). `getUser()` only had a small change which was required for my application.